# Compiling C++ code raising "no input files" fatal error?

Tags: compiling, c++

I am finding it hard to run/compile a simple C++ code in the terminal. Here's the code I am using to compile the file (helloworld.cpp).

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

I am getting an error. (Image)

[image: g++: fatal error: no input files]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the code file (in this case `helloworld.cpp`) in your current working directory. If the code file is in a different directory, you need to specify where in the command. For example

```
g++ some/other/folder/helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.o
```